# cakephp Error: Association is already bound to model Indicator TranslateBehavior.php

Tags: cakephp

I have been working with cakePHP 2, recently and I have found some weird errors with the i18n translation when I try to instantiate or manage objects...

For example now I have the following error:

Error: Association IndicatornameTranslation is already bound to model Indicator
File: /home3/siriarte/public_html/css/lib/Cake/Model/Behavior/TranslateBehavior.php
Line: 630

The line that is producing this error is:

```
        $Indicator = new Indicator();
```

In the following code:

```
public function getRelatedIndicators($id) {

    App::uses('Indicatornode', 'Model');
    App::uses('Indicator', 'Model');

    $Indicatornode = new Indicatornode();
    $r = $Indicatornode->find('all',array(
        'conditions'=>array("node_id"=>$id),
        'recursive'=>-1
    ));

    if (is_array($r)) {
        foreach($r as $r2) {
            $re[]=$r2["Indicatornode"]["indicator_id"];
        }
    }

    if (is_array($re)and sizeof($re)) {
        $Indicator = new Indicator();
        $Indicator->setLanguage();
        $rel=$Indicator->find('all', array("conditions"=>array("Indicator.id"=>$re), 'recursive'=>-1, 'order'=>"Indicator.name"));
        return $rel;
    }

    return array();

}
```

This code is inside a Model called "Node"

The definition of the Model "Indicator" which is the one that gives the error with the translation model (I think) is:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Indicator Model
 *
 */

class Indicator extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $actsAs = array(
         'Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'),
         'Translate' => array(
            'name' => 'IndicatornameTranslation',
            'metric' => 'IndicatormetricTranslation', 
            'description' => 'IndicatordescriptionTranslation'
        )
    );

    public $locale = 'esp';

....
```

Anyone have had a similar error message before in cake?

Any help where to start the debug?

Thanks....

Comment: I solved the problem moving the method to another object, not a terrible solution, but anyway i am courious about this because I have had the same error a few times....

Comment: You should start with not instantiating model classes manually, that's a _no-go_! Use [**`ClassRegistry::init()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init) instead.

Comment: Txs I will keep this in mind